# Chrome 32 - control emulation via JS or webdriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, google-chrome-devtools, selenium-chromedriver

I love the [new emulation feature introduced in the new Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/mobile-emulation). In fact so much that I like to use it to test a mobile website for multiple resolutions/devices. To do so I would require some sort of control over the emulation feature.

**Is there any way to control wish device is emulated?**

It would be nice to know how to start `OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver` emulating a mobile device.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is this: https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=399 specifically see comment #3.

Comment: humm... do you know how to check the progress on that item?

Comment: @vtortola Check for commits from "Samuel Rawlins" in the source? Or ask in that issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding options to the Chrome driver.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3");
```

In the above example, "user-agent" switch has been provided. Similarly please try using "window-size" command line switch.

Please let me know if it works.

List of all command line switches of chrome are provided below.

http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

NOTE: By installing the Chrome plugin given below, you can get the required user-agent settings for various devices.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it in C#:

```
IWebDriver driver;
        string setDevice = "Apple iPhone 6";
        var mobileEmulation = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "deviceName", setDevice } };
        var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.AddAdditionalCapability( "mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation );
        driver = new ChromeDriver( chromeOptions );
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout( TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 90 ) );
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait( TimeSpan.FromSeconds( Convert.ToDouble( 30 ) ) );
        return driver;
```